# How to set the min and max of the original array in sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I am looking at

```
class sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1), copy=True
```

which has a description as follows:
The standardization is given by:

```
X_std = (X - X.min(axis=0)) / (X.max(axis=0) - X.min(axis=0))
X_scaled = X_std * (max - min) + min
```

As shown above, it assumes that the minimum of the original array is X.min(axis=0). Is there a way I can specify a different minimum w.r.t which I want the data to be scaled?

For ex: I want the original range to be [0-255] and the final range to be [0-1]. Now if the original array does not contain the value 0, the least value will be taken as minimum which I don't want to consider.

Comment: I would have a look at the source code https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a95203b/sklearn/preprocessing/data.py#L178 it's quite short.

Comment: @London guy , I ran into the same issue. How did you solve your problem?

Comment: I got it: First time you call `scaler.fit_transform(myOriginalDataset)` and for the second dataset that should use the same min max range I call `scaler.transform(mySecondDataset)`

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array `X_train` `[1,2,3,4,5,6] you can also "add" a new minimum value to it:

```
X_train_help = numpy.append(X_train, 0)
```

Then you run the `fit`method on the help array:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
scaler.fit(X_train_help)
```

and transform it on the old data:

```
scaler.transform(X_train)
```